# Microsoft Access: Using an unshown field to filter results doesn't execute False Null evaluation

Tags: ms-access

I'm using a form with text boxes the user can input values and filter out results from a query in the form. When the box is a null I'd like to return all of the results for that field, null or not. I've made an unshown field with this code:

Field:  `IIf(IsNull([Forms]![frmCriteriaInQuery]![txtrecast]),[Recast Layer],[Recast Layer]<=[Forms]![frmCriteriaInQuery]![txtRecast])`

Criteria: `<>False`

When I run the form it doesn't return the null values or the 0's. I've tried a number of things that give me syntax errors.
I'm not sure what the issue is, very new to Access and SQL though.

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data. What is [Recast Layer]?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [Recast Layer] field is a number type, consider:

Field: `IIf([Forms]![frmCriteriaInQuery]![txtRecast] Is Null And [Recast Layer] Is Null, 0, [Recast Layer])<=Nz([Forms]![frmCriteriaInQuery]![txtRecast], Nz([Recast Layer],0))`

Criteria: `True`

Comment: [Recast Layer] doesn't always have a value. It may be null.

Comment: Try revised answer.